# Batch Copy file to another direction

Tags: batch-file, copy

This code doesn't work well. This should copy created file to another directory. But this code don't copy anything and i don't see where I made mistake

```
@echo off

dir *.txt>>Alek.txt

for %%x in %1 do echo %%x>>"%2"


copy  "h:\bat\zad\a\Alek.txt" "h:\bat\zad\b" 






:pause
```

Comment: It's the copy line that's giving you trouble? Is there an error or is nothing simply happening?

Comment: Are you trying to copy the text from one file to another, or just copy the entire file?

Comment: Just want copy the entire file

Comment: What are you trying to do with the line `for %%x in %1 do echo %%x>>"%2"`?

Comment: SomethingDark no there is no error Alek.txt is created but problems appears when i want copy it to another destination folder

Comment: Joe M So it is about list of files in folder when my bat file is . This line is writing:  Wolumin w stacji H nie ma etykiety.
 Numer seryjny woluminu: 6C30-E02D

 Katalog: H:\bat\zad\a

2014-11-11  16:16                38 Alek.txt
2014-11-11  15:20                 6 das.txt
2014-11-11  15:20                11 dsada.txt
2014-11-11  15:20                10 sadge.txt
2014-11-11  15:24               188 zad23.txt
               5 plik(˘w)                253 bajt˘w
               0 katalog(˘w)  130˙804˙752˙384 bajt˘w wolnych
in Alek.txt

Comment: There will always be some sort of error if it didn't work. That said, it's likely that it's doing something you aren't expecting it to do. I'm guessing it's getting copied to a file called b in the h:\bat\zad directory.

Comment: Agree with above.  If the folder `b` doesn't already exist, it will write into a file called `b`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the third line to this:

```
for /f %%x in %1 do echo %%x>>"%2"
```

If you're trying to write the contents of the file to another file.  But that will only work inside a batch file that you pass two parameters into.